# How to call reducer function of one slice to another slice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Slice One

```
/*eslint-disable*/
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = { };

const patientSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'Patient Slice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    TestingOtherSliceCall: (state: any, { payload }: any) => { 
      alert('heelllo im from patient slice');
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [GetInsurancePayersFilter.pending]: (state: any) => { 
      state.loadingInsurancePayersFilter = true;
    },
    [GetInsurancePayersFilter.fulfilled]: (state: any, { payload }: PayloadAction<TPayloadList>) => {
      state.loadingInsurancePayersFilter = false; 
      state.getInsurancePayersFilter = payload;
    },
    [GetInsurancePayersFilter.rejected]: (state: any) => { 
      state.loadingInsurancePayersFilter = false;
    },
  }
});

export const { TestingOtherSliceCall patientSlice.actions;

export const patientReducer = patientSlice.reducer;
```

Slice Two

```
/*eslint-disable*/
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TestingOtherSliceCall } from './patient';

const initialState = {};

insurance end    ******** */ 
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'User Slice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    DynamicTabAppend: (state: any, { payload }) => { 
      TestingOtherSliceCall(null);
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {

  }
});

export const { TestingOtherSliceCall userSlice.actions;

export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```

Root Reducer

```
import { patientReducer } from './../slices/patient';
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { createFilter } from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  patient: patientReducer,
});

export const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['auth', 'schedule'],
};

export const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

I tried calling from one slice reducer to another but function does'nt invoke.

Comment: Reducers are pure functions that take a previous state and an action, and return the next state. They don't do side-effects like call other functions. What are you trying to accomplish here? Can you [edit] the post to format the code into a more readable format and provide better details for the use case or problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to "call" two reducers on one action, add the action to the `extraReducers` of both reducers. Also, please switch to the "builder notation" for `extraReducers`, the object notation you are using here is deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: Okay...
My Main problem is I have A page in which you can append tab dynamically. And it has one Tab panel component.. On basis of tab click content in panel component change. 
suppose I have a input field and dropdown in panel while in tab1 i write something and select a option from dropdown, then i click tab2 and write something in input and select something from dropdown. but when i select tab1 back my states are lost even if i store it in redux.